# DB2 temp tables with no scroll cursor

Tags: db2

Does DB2 no scroll cursor have sensitivity to inserts, updates, or deletes that are made to the rows underlying the result table?

Comment: This depends on your Db2-version, Db2-platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) and the exact syntax you use from which programming language.  Without those details your question is too vague.

Comment: Among other things, one of the big ones is going to be the isolation/transaction level.  But any time somebody is asking a question along these lines, I get the feeling they're not preparing for concurrency, and/or thinking too much along imperative/application programmer lines (say, RBAR).  When somebody adds/deletes/changes a row when someone else is reading the table, what do you want to happen?  Although note that reader behavior is per-instance, not global.  What is it you're trying to do?